# Is there any difference between "TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP" and "dp in xml"?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my App I am specifying the width of a few elements dynamically using

```
TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, mycontext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I am also using some other elements whose width are specified in the layout xml in dp terms.

However when I run the app on my Samsung Galaxy Grand, I observe that 100 dip specifed dynamically is not exactly equal to 100 dp specified in the layout xml(slightly more).

However, when I test it on a AVD it appears to be fine(both width matches).

Has anyone else encountered this issue as well?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

I was doing :

```
int pixels_unit_five = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, mycontext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Then I was using ths value for views with different widths like:

```
android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_item = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pixels_unit_five*20,pixels_unit_five*8 );

android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_item = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pixels_unit_five*10,pixels_unit_five*8 );
```

And so on..

The dip value is being cast to int and that was doing minor rounding off to fit the exact pixel value.This, when multiplied by 20 added up to a considerable difference in pixel value.

Solved it by obtaining exact dip value straightaway and using them.